# Big Oh worst case analysis - if statement inside loop

Tags: algorithm, if-statement, time-complexity, big-o, complexity-theory

For the worst-case analysis of the code below I think it's O(n^2), however my prof states its O(n), arguing that the  maximum amount of operations per element is 2 (one push and one pop).

- Since its an `if-statement`, isn't it one or the other? How is it both push and pop?
- If it's the "worst-case" why can we not argue first pushing n-1 elements, and then for the very last iteration looping through the entire stack, resulting in O(n^2)?

```
void foo (int n){
    Stack<int> stack = new Stack();

    i = 0;

    while (i < n) {
        int key = random int from 1 to n
        
        if (key is odd) 
            stack.push(key);
        else {
            j = 0;

            while (j < key and !stack.isEmpty()){
                stack.pop();

            j = j + 1;
        }

        i = i + 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: If you're counting apples, you know you can take them, reorganize them into groups, and count the groups. You can rearrange them any way that you want which is convenient. Your prof is just doing that with work instead of apples.  He can rearrange units of work done and tally it up. He's just grouping the work by what element it was done to.

Comment: You are _both_ entirely correct. Worst-case scenario it *does* take a maximum of `O(n)`, and there are `n` steps, so _it is_ `O(n^2)`. However, this has been _amortized_ by `O(1)` for n - 1, so _it is also_ `O(n - 1 + n) = O(2n-1) = O(n)`; this is a tighter bound.

Comment: @Neil: you are right, but the OP's argument about the very last iteration is wrong, as there is only one very last...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a tricky question! Your professor is approaching the problem with a different paradigm than you are (which is sometimes helpful). Instead of thinking about this problem in terms of what the loops will do, it can be helpful to think about it in terms of how many times each element operated on will be "touched".

For this problem, you are going to "touch" *n* integers during the execution of the program -- these are the "elements" you are operating on. For each element, think about what your program can do with it. What do you think?

You can either *push* that element onto your stack OR you can *pop* it off, right?

Next, think about this question: Is it possible to push an element (an integer) that *has already been on the stack* back onto the stack?

The answer is no. Once an integer has been pushed onto the stack, the while loop will never return to that integer. The variable *i* always increments but never decrements.

So, for each element, of which there are *n*, you can *at most* push it onto the stack once and pop it off at most once. Asymptotically, that works out to *O(n)* complexity.

In the future, when you're working on figuring out a tricky problem like this one, try to see if changing your paradigm helps to figure it out. :)

Answer (score 1):

Your teacher is absolutely right.

- there are at most `n` pushes, so there cannot be more than `n` pops. This justifies `O(n)`. [The "very last iteration looping through the stack" would result in just `O(n)`.]
- when an odd number is pushed, it can be later popped [in your own "very last" example, all elements but one could be pushed then popped].

Answer (score 1):

Apologies for contributing an answer with so many correct responses, but it might be easier to explain with a diagram. You are correct in your assessment of the worst-case, where the stack builds with odd numbers and finally as the last one `n` or `n-1`, an even number, causes the stack to empty completely. In this case, a rough diagram of the work done, vertical, *per* time on the horizontal for one `n`.

[image: 1 until the last, which is n]

The maximum work *per* step is `n`, and there are `n` steps. It is true that the problem is in `O(n^2)`. This corresponds to filling a square `n x n`: `\sum_{t=1}^{n} n = n^2 \in O(n^2)`. *Also* your teacher is right; by splitting the work into two parts, you can achieve a tighter bound: `sum_{t=1}^{n-1} 1 + n = n - 1 + n = 2n - 1 \in O(n)`.

[image: Amortized analysis.]

One might also ask what is the run-time of the inner loop? The worst-case is also `O(n)` because that one where the stack empties. Times `n`, is `O(n^2)`. In [amortized analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amortized_analysis), you look at a sequence of operations. Thus, you can borrow a from a high value to even it out. This is `O(1)` amortized *per* step.

Comment: I would not recommend promoting the rule: "number of iterations times the worst-case complexity of a single iteration". In the given case, that leads to a gross overestimate. Technically correct, but so untight !

Comment: @YvesDaoust that is a good point. For the OP, *any* bound equal or greater than `O(n)` is an answer; usually the best is the tightest. In fact, I think we can say a stronger condition, the algorithm is [Θ(n)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Family_of_Bachmann%E2%80%93Landau_notations).

Comment: "For the OP, any bound equal or greater than O(n) is an answer": mh, I do think that the OP believed that the right answer is obtained by n.O(n) = O(n²) *and this is tight*.

Answer (score 0):

The best case scenario here would be that every drawn random value is even.  In this case, each iteration of the loop would just no-op.  No items would be pushed to the stack or popped from the stack.  In the worst case scenario, each drawn random value would be odd.  In this case, each item would be pushed onto the stack.

In both best and worst case, the running time of the loop is `O(n)`.  However, in the worst case scenario, the loop would also need `O(n)` storage space for the stack.

Note that worst case behavior of drawing many odds followed by drawing an even does not change the loop complexity, which is still `O(n)`.

Comment: The worst case is negotiable. You can as well get n-1 pushes and n-1 pops, rather than just n pushes. (Of course in the asymptotic sense that makes no difference.)

Comment: @YvesDaoust Yes, it might introduce a factor of 2 but would not alter running time or space complexity.

Comment: You mean *asymptotic* complexity. It does change the ordinary complexity and the running time.

Comment: I think @YvesDaoust meant that although for the big-O notation coefficients do not matter, for the number of steps it's not quite correct to say that (in terms of running time) the worst case is n odds, because it leads to just n pushes, while n-1 odds plus 1 even lead to n-1 pushes and n-1 pops.